# como fazer um gráfico em vba excel em forma de metas?

Tags: vba, excel-vba

preciso fazer um gráfico em que as barras mudem de cor dependendo de seu valor!
exemplo: menor que mil vermelho, entre mil e dois mil amarelo e acima de mil verde segue imagem [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

## VBA

Um código simples de ser utilizado é este, onde o gráfico deve ser selecionado e depois o código é executado:

```
Sub ColorByValue()
'https://peltiertech.com/vba-conditional-formatting-of-charts-by-value/
'http://www.clearlyandsimply.com/clearly_and_simply/2011/08/color-coded-bar-charts-with-microsoft-excel.html

Dim rPatterns As Range
Dim iPattern As Long
Dim vPatterns As Variant
Dim iPoint As Long
Dim vValues As Variant
Dim rValue As Range

Set rPatterns = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A4")
vPatterns = rPatterns.Value
With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
    vValues = .Values
        For j = LBound(vValues) To UBound(vValues)
        Debug.Print vValues(j)
        Next j
    For iPoint = 1 To UBound(vValues)
        For iPattern = 1 To UBound(vPatterns)
            If vValues(iPoint) <= vPatterns(iPattern, 1) Then
                .Points(iPoint).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = _
                                                          rPatterns.Cells(iPattern, 1).Interior.Color
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

Em que os valores de limite para colorir o gráfico são colocados na coluna A da planilha, exemplo: [image: Limites do gráfico] e esta parte do código alterada para o intervalo usado:  `Set rPatterns = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A4")`

Cada célula com o valor do limite deve possuir a cor do interior que deve ser usada.

E o resultado:

[image: Resultado]

#### Observação:

Se ocorrer algum erro, os dados devem possuir a coluna invertida:

```
+------+----+
| 2700 |  1 |
| 1100 |  2 |
| 3000 |  3 |
| 2100 |  4 |
| 3000 |  5 |
|  900 |  6 |
| 2900 |  7 |
|  600 |  8 |
|  300 |  9 |
| 1100 | 10 |
| 2000 | 11 |
| 2300 | 12 |
| 1700 | 13 |
| 2700 | 14 |
|    0 | 15 |
+------+----+
```

Ou esta parte do código mudada para: `With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2)`

## Excel Fórmula

Não é necessário utilizar o VBA para realizar isto, pode ser feito somente com fórmulas. Pois com VBA é um pouco mais complexo e isto é feito mais rapidamente e simples com as fórmulas.

Por exemplo, você possui esta tabela com valores:

```
+------+-------+
|   A  |   B   |
+------+-------+
|    1 |  2700 |
|    2 |  1100 |
|    3 |  3000 |
|    4 |  2100 |
|    5 |  3000 |
|    6 |   900 |
|    7 |  2900 |
|    8 |   600 |
|    9 |   300 |
|   10 |  1100 |
|   11 |  2000 |
|   12 |  2300 |
|   13 |  1700 |
|   14 |  2700 |
|   15 |     0 |
+------+-------+
```

E deseja três intervalos, um para cada cor:

- **Vermelho**: se a coluna B for **menor** do que 1000.
- **Amarelo**: se a coluna B for **maior ou igual** a 1000 **e menor** do que 2000.
- **Verde**: se a coluna B for **maior ou igual** a 2000.

Portanto, três colunas serão utilizadas ao lado dos valores da coluna B para verificar quais valores estão dentro destes intervalos e criar uma série de dados para cada coluna nova.

As formulas são as seguintes:

- Para o vermelho: `=SE(B2<1000;B2;"")`
- Para o amarelo: `=SE(E(B2>=1000;B2<2000);B2;"")`
- Para o verde: `=SE(B2>=2000;B2;"")`

Em que se estiver dentro do intervalo, o valor é inserido na célula, caso contrário é deixado o valor em branco `""`.

Resultando na seguinte tabela:

```
+----+------+----------+---------+-------+
| A  |  B   | Vermelho | Amarelo | Verde |
+----+------+----------+---------+-------+
|  1 | 2700 |          |         |  2700 |
|  2 | 1100 |          |    1100 |       |
|  3 | 3000 |          |         |  3000 |
|  4 | 2100 |          |         |  2100 |
|  5 | 3000 |          |         |  3000 |
|  6 |  900 |      900 |         |       |
|  7 | 2900 |          |         |  2900 |
|  8 |  600 |      600 |         |       |
|  9 |  300 |      300 |         |       |
| 10 | 1100 |          |    1100 |       |
| 11 | 2000 |          |         |  2000 |
| 12 | 2300 |          |         |  2300 |
| 13 | 1700 |          |    1700 |       |
| 14 | 2700 |          |         |  2700 |
| 15 |    0 |        0 |         |       |
+----+------+----------+---------+-------+
```

Com isto, um gráfico pode ser inserido em: `Inserir > Gráfico Coluna Agrupada` e depois ir em `Selecionar Dados`.

Cada coluna nova deverá ser adicionada como uma nova série de dados:

[image: Adicionar dados]

Os dados adicionados de cada série, são os valores de cada coluna:

[image: Valores Série]

Por fim, cada série de dados do gráfico deve ser selecionada e sua cor trocada:

[image: Trocar cor da série de dados]